# How to do an animate plot in MATLAB from a sequence of matrices

Tags: matlab, visualization, montecarlo, colormap

I have code that uses Wolff's Algorithm to simulate the XY Model in MATLAB and I want to implement a pcolor/color map to demonstrate each spin according to their angles across the system. But I want it to be live and changing as the angles change.

Any idea how to do this?

This is an example of how I want it to look https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSp7s.png

Answer (score 0):

If you save each snapshot of the lattice in a cell array A{t}, you can use the following function to view and save it as a video (if fileName is not empty, the function saves an mp4 video).

Another option is to adapt the function `view_lattice` to run your simulation (which, honestly, I wouldn't recommend, for performance issues). I will mark where you should edit for doing a "live" simulation

This is at least MATLAB R2019b (although it may be compatible with earlier versions, but no guarantee).

File `view_lattice.m`

```
function view_lattice(A,fileName)
% for a 'live' simulation, you will have to remove A from the input 
% parameters and add the ones you need for the XY Wolff algorithm,
% which will be used to calculate each configuration A in the time loop below
% you will also need to remove the assert statements for 'live' simulation
%
% otherwise, you save snapshots from your simulation
% and use this function as is
% 
% A -> A{k}[m,n] snapshot k containing the angles of spins in lattice site at row m and col n
% fileName -> if contains string, then records a video with the snapshots and name it with this string
    assert(iscell(A) && all(cellfun(@(a)isnumeric(a) && ismatrix(a),A)),'A must be cell of numeric matrices');
    assert(ischar(fileName),'fileName must be either an empty char or contain a file name');
    
    recordVideo = ~isempty(fileName);
    
    if recordVideo
        vw = setup_video(fileName);
    else
        vw = [];
    end
    % setting some default axis properties to speed-up plotting
    set(0,'DefaultAxesPlotBoxAspectRatio',[1 1 1],'DefaultAxesDataAspectRatioMode','manual','DefaultAxesDataAspectRatio',[1,1,1],'DefaultAxesNextPlot','replace');
    
    fh = figure;
    ax=axes;
    for t = 1:numel(A) % for 'live' simulation, this loop should be the time loop
        % here you calculate the new configuration A
        % and call the function below with A instead of A{t}
        vw = record_frame(vw,fh,ax,A{t},t,recordVideo);
    end
    
    % any video to close?
    if recordVideo
        vw.close();
    end
end

function vw = record_frame(vw,fh,ax,A,t,recordVideo)
    imagesc(ax,A);
    title(ax,sprintf('snapshot %g',t)); % if you want, y
    axis(ax,'square');
    daspect(ax,[1,1,1]);
    pause(0.01);
    if recordVideo
        vframe = getframe(fh);
        vw.writeVideo(vframe);
    end
end

function vw = setup_video(fileName)
    vid_id = num2str(rand,'%.16g');
    vid_id = vid_id(3:6);
    vid_id = [fileName,'_',vid_id];
    % Initialize video
    vw = VideoWriter([vid_id,'.mp4'], 'MPEG-4'); %open video file
    vw.Quality = 100;
    vw.FrameRate = 16;
    vw.open();
end
```

Test script: `test.m`

```
clearvars
close all

A = cell(1,30);

for t = 1:numel(A)
    % creating a sequence of random snapshots only for illustration
    A{t} = rand(20,20);
end

% viewing the animation and saving it as a video with name test
view_lattice(A,'test');
```

Output

[image: Random lattice]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not too great at MATLAB and I'm essentially adapting code so I'll need to get back to you on whether this works for what I need.